# How can I create custom projected coordinate system in arcpy?

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.3

I want to create my own projected coordinate system based on one of geographical coordinate systems and set custom values to properties as `longitude`, `scaleFactor` etc.

I found [SpatialReference](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z0000000v000000) class.

But can't understand how set geographical coordinate system that will be base for my coordinate system - `GCS` property is read only, and no methods for set its value.

And also, when I calls `create` method, result is `RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function`.

Article has example with only reading existing property, but hasn't examples with creating CS.

What am I doing wrong, and where can I find examples for CS creating?

My code:

```
new_sr = arcpy.SpatialReference()
new_sr.linearUnitName = u'meters'
new_sr.longitude = 30
new_sr.longitudeOf1st = 10
new_sr.longitudeOf2nd = 50
new_sr.longitudeOfOrigin = 30
new_sr.projectionCode = 100500
new_sr.projectionName = u'my_projection'
new_sr.scaleFactor = 2
new_sr.standardParallel1 = 50
new_sr.standardParallel2 = 60
new_sr.create() # RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function
```

May be I must set some other properties, or vice versa remove unnessecary?

Comment: Well, you have too many parameters for one. The projectionCode and projectionName are the map projection algorithm you want to use like 43020 or "Lambert_Conformal_Conic." 100500 isn't valid. Look in the Documentation folder for projected_coordinate_systems.pdf for the list of projections and parameters that are used with each one.

Comment: Thanks, [JamesSLC](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/9669/jamesslc) already answered. And code from my question is non-working because ```arcpy.SpatialReference``` can't change values for some reason (this magic is described in [article](https://arcpy.wordpress.com/2013/06/21/altering-spatial-references-in-python/)), not only because of wrong parameters count or values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your initial question, *'how set geographical coordinate system that will be base for my coordinate system - GCS property is read only, and no methods for set its value*'

You can use a numeric code for either a projected or geographic coordinate system when creating the `Spatial Reference` Object, like this:

```
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(104926)
```

ESRI provides a list of projected and geographic coordinate systems and their numeric codes [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/002z/pdf/geographic_coordinate_systems.pdf). I used 104926 it is the code for GCS_Atlas_2000 which is a geographic coordinate system. When you initiate a `Spatial Reference` object with a numeric code a valid `Spatial Reference` Object is returned. You can then access its properties. Editing a `Spatial Reference` Object can be quite tricky ([see here](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/30280)), however you can pick and choose the properties you want from the created spatial reference to populate your custom spatial reference.

At the very least you can export your *base* spatial reference with `sr.exportToString()` and manually edit the properties you want to change in the string and/or file you output the string to. Definitely not ideal, but it will get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in the recently added `arcpy.GenerateOptimalCoordinateSystem` function, see doc at https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/generateoptimalcoordinatesystem.htm.